# How to modify a new react application?

Tags: reactjs

This might be a bit confusing but my issue is that when we create a new react app typing npx create-react-app in terminal of windows. A whole functioning application is created, but what is the best way to modify it so that I can practice to create it on my own(talking about html and JS files only).

I've tried to delete all the written code in src file and tried to re-react it my self but there are always some errors.

Comment: Why don't you use a single `index.html` file with a `index.js` and `style.css` file?

Comment: You can delete the whole application folder, recreate the application and then modify the code in src/App.js file.

Comment: @devpolo how is that react? That will be plain JS, wont that be?